# How to Sort ArrayList of Objects by a field without Comparator / Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist, comparable

I have an arraylist of objects  which cannot implement the Comparator / Comparable interface.

The objects have a field : 'SequenceNumber' which is an integer. I need to sort the arraylist in order of this field (lowest to highest) without implementing the mentioned interfaces.

Is there an easy way to do this, I can manually write a sorting algorithm but wondering if there is a more efficient (and more bug-free) way of doing this which I have missed while searching?

Note : Using Java 7.

Comment: Yes, use Comparator

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the objects are unable to implement Comparator

Comment: Why do you need to sort without using those 2 interfaces? They are designed to help you do sorting.

Comment: @ControlAltDel is it not? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: @AshFrench The objects are part of a core code base, I am only creating a plugin which utilises them and I don't want to affect these objects in any way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a comparator class to handle sorting:

```
private class MyObjectComparator<MyObject> implements Comparator<MyObject> {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
     return o2.getSequenceNumber() - o1.getSequenceNumber();
  }

}
```

Then sort your `ArrayList` with it:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new MyObjectComparator());
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use lambda expression introduced in Java8 to sort objects without implementing Comparable/Comparator interface.

Below is the code snippet to sort and display objects using lambda.

```
class Student
{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    public Student(int id, String name) 
    {  
        this.id = id;  
        this.name = name;  
    }
    public  String toString()
    {
        return id +" " +name;
    }
}
public class SortDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();  

        //Adding Objects  
        list.add(new Student(1,"XYZ"));  
        list.add(new Student(3,"ABC"));  
        list.add(new Student(2,"PQR"));  

        System.out.println("Sorting on the basis of name...");  

        // implementing lambda expression  
        Collections.sort(list,(p1,p2)->{return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);});  

        list.forEach((s)->System.out.println(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: OP uses Java 7.

Comment: The lambda is still fulfilling the Comparator interface in the method call: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-