# Sort ArrayList of Objects, WITHOUT Class Getters. Possible?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a lambda expression to sort an ArrayList of Objects (i.e. rows imported from a CSV file), WITHOUT classes (like "Employee", or "Person", or "Animal", etc.), so there are no Getters/Setters for the Objects at all. So I'm essentially BufferedReading in rows from a CSV file, assigning them to objects, and adding those objects to an ArrayList. I want to then sort by the last value/index in each object. For example...

These are my CSV rows:

```
Mark,10,0,34
Tom,2,0,19
Billy,2,0,7
```

...and I would like to sort them by the far right numbers in ascending order, so my sorted ArrayList would look like:

```
Billy,2,0,7
Tom,2,0,19
Mark,10,0,34
```

Is this even possible using a lambda expression? What I have for code so far looks like this:

```
// Import the csv file and assign each row to a list of objects
List<Object> olReturn = null;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stats_log.csv"))) {
                
    olReturn = br.lines().sorted((x,y) -> x.LASTVALUEHERE() - y.LASTVALUEHERE()).collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
            
for (Object obIndObject : olReturn) {
    System.out.println(obIndObject);
}
```

I know how to do it if the object classes had getters for the values I want to sort by, but that doesn't apply here, so just seeing if there's a potential solution, or if it's impossible?

Comment: If you're planning to use instances of the base `Object` class, where are you going to put your data?

Comment: All the data is going to be used for is for displaying purposes. I just read in the CSV lines, assign them to (albeit empty) objects, and slap em into an ArrayList. Ideally, I then just want to sort that ArrayList by the last index (-1) of each Object, short of that, I won't be using the Objects anywhere else in the program. Does that help, or did I miss the question entirely? :')

Comment: Definitely not an `ArrayList`. You want to arrange them in some "natural" order. `ArrayList` adds elements in sequential order.

Comment: The point is that `Object` is a type of object that isn't going to be able to store names or numbers.  In order to sort and display information, you have to have some way to store it.  If you don't want to define your own classes, you could in theory just use `String`s and `Integers`s, but that's a clunky anti-pattern compared to creating a proper data class.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something. Assigning a string to a variable of type `Object` doesn't automagically change the runtime type of that string. You can refer to it as `Object string = "whatever"` as much as you want, but that doesn't change the fact that it's still a `String`.

Comment: @MattWilson I think you are over complicating things. Each read line is a `String`. String objects are comparable. You can arrange them in alphabetical order.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, not using a lambda expression, but implementing a version of the solution from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045952/how-to-sort-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-field-without-comparator-comparable/40046032

I'll post my solution above when I get it working, I think it'll work...

Comment: @MattWilson as I stated before, you were over complicating matters. All you need is to capture each line (String) and take advantage of the fact that strings are "sortable" (Comparable) and can be easily sorted when using the right collection object.

Comment: Negative, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking, how to sort by the LAST VALUE of the Objects (or Strings in this case). I don't just want a simple alphabetical sort to happen, however further to what I think you're suggesting, take a look at my solution when I post it in a couple of minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen he clarified in my posted answer that he doesn't want or need to sort alphabetically. He needs to sort by one of the numeric values in the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
List < String > sorted =
                List.of(
                        "Mark,10,0,34" ,
                        "Tom,2,7,19" ,
                        "Billy,2,0,7"
                )
                .stream()
                .sorted( ( String s1 , String s2 ) -> Integer.valueOf( s1.split( "," )[ 3 ] ).compareTo( Integer.valueOf( s2.split( "," )[ 3 ] ) ) )
                .toList();
```

## Streams

You asked:

> use a lambda expression to sort an ArrayList of Objects (i.e. rows imported from a CSV file),

In other words, you want to sort a list of `String` objects by the last part delimited with a COMMA (`,`).

For each string, we need to do a `String#split` call, returning an array of parts. We expect exactly four parts given your example data. So take the last part. Arrays in Java annoyingly use an index, that is, zero-based counting. So the 4th item is an index of 3, syntactically `[3]`.

This code is *not* efficient, as sorting involves many repetitive calls to `compareTo`. For each call we are performing the splitting all over again.  Not efficient, but it works.

```java
List < String > inputs =
        new ArrayList <>(
                List.of(
                        "Mark,10,0,34" ,
                        "Tom,2,7,19" ,
                        "Billy,2,0,7"
                )
        );

List < String > sorted =
        inputs
                .stream()
                .sorted( ( String s1 , String s2 ) -> Integer.valueOf( s1.split( "," )[ 3 ] ).compareTo( Integer.valueOf( s2.split( "," )[ 3 ] ) ) )
                .toList();  // Before Java 16: .collect( Collectors.toList() );

System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/y6k2hH).

> sorted = [Billy,2,0,7, Tom,2,7,19, Mark,10,0,34]

## Records

Your Question really does not make sense in that it explicitly avoids using classes. Java is an object-oriented language. Classes are its bread-and-butter, its *raison d'être*.

If you are simply reluctant to define a class because of the requisite boilerplate, I have good news for you. Java 16 brings the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature.

Records are a brief way to declare a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You simply declare the types and names of all the class member fields. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

So an entire class can be written on one short line.

```java
record Person ( String name , int departmentId , int projectId , int employeeId ) {}
```

Populate a collection of `Person` objects based on your input data.

```java
List < Person > persons = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    String[] parts = input.split( "," );
    Person p = new Person( parts[ 0 ] , Integer.valueOf( parts[ 1 ] ) , Integer.valueOf( parts[ 2 ] )  , Integer.valueOf( parts[ 3 ] ) );
    persons.add( p );
}
```

Sort that list by the last member field, `employeeId`.

```java
Collections.sort(
        persons ,
        new Comparator < Person >()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare ( Person p1 , Person p2 )
            {
                return Integer.compare( p1.employeeId() , p2.employeeId() );
            }
        }
);
```

Here is complete example.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class RecordDemo
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < String > inputs =
                new ArrayList <>(
                        List.of(
                                "Mark,10,0,34" ,
                                "Tom,2,7,19" ,
                                "Billy,2,0,7"
                        )
                );

        record Person(String name , int departmentId , int projectId , int employeeId)
        {
        }

        List < Person > persons = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
        for ( String input : inputs )
        {
            String[] parts = input.split( "," );
            Person p = new Person( parts[ 0 ] , Integer.valueOf( parts[ 1 ] ) , Integer.valueOf( parts[ 2 ] ) , Integer.valueOf( parts[ 3 ] ) );
            persons.add( p );
        }
        System.out.println( "persons = " + persons );

        Collections.sort(
                persons ,
                new Comparator < Person >()
                {
                    @Override
                    public int compare ( Person p1 , Person p2 )
                    {
                        return Integer.compare( p1.employeeId() , p2.employeeId() );
                    }
                }
        );
        System.out.println( "persons = " + persons );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
persons = [Person[name=Mark, departmentId=10, projectId=0, employeeId=34], Person[name=Tom, departmentId=2, projectId=7, employeeId=19], Person[name=Billy, departmentId=2, projectId=0, employeeId=7]]
persons = [Person[name=Billy, departmentId=2, projectId=0, employeeId=7], Person[name=Tom, departmentId=2, projectId=7, employeeId=19], Person[name=Mark, departmentId=10, projectId=0, employeeId=34]]
```

In that code above, notice another nice thing about records: You can **declare records locally**, within a method, as well as nested in a class or in a separate class (.java file). And while the Java team was at it, they now allow **local enum definitions**, and **local interface definitions** too. All that is in Java 16 and later.

Comment: *`public record Person(...`

Comment: This is great, similar to my posted solution, but I like the way it's set up lambda wise. I KNOW java likes objects :P it's just the way I set up this project this one time unfortunately. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @onkarruikar Yes! `record`, not `class`. Old habits die hard.

Comment: Why not use `Comparator.comparingInt()`?

Answer (score 1):

I updated based on the OP's comment

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<String> list =
        Arrays.asList("Mark,10,0,34", "Wyle,2,0,19", "Tom,2,0,19", "Billy,2,0,7");
    
    Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare (String o1, String o2) {
            int diff = (Integer.valueOf(o1.substring(o1.lastIndexOf(',')+1))).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.substring(o2.lastIndexOf(',')+1)));
            return (diff == 0)
                ? o1.compareTo(o2)
                : diff;
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(list, cmp);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

This outputs:
`[Billy,2,0,7, Tom,2,0,19, Wyle,2,0,19, Mark,10,0,34]`

This example will compare based on the last set of numbers OR alphabetically cases where the last set of numbers are the same.

Comment: I know this would sort the list alphabetically, however I don't want that. I need to sort by the last number in the string, so even if one of them starts with an "a", I don't want it showing at the top if the last number of its string was a bigger number than the one after it. I've figured out a solution that I will post shortly...thanks!

Comment: That's pretty close to what I implemented, only with the added bonus of alphabetical as the second sort by. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattWilson I corrected a small error in the logic and added a case for dup value at the end so you could see how it will resolve like numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's not using a lambda expression, however I was able to modify the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045952/how-to-sort-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-field-without-comparator-comparable/40046032) to fit my needs. Take a look:

This is the custom Comparator class:

```
private class MyObjectComparator<MyObject> implements Comparator<MyObject> {
      /**
       * {@inheritDoc}
       */
      @Override
      public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
         return Integer.parseInt(o1.toString().split(",")[3]) - Integer.parseInt(o2.toString().split(",")[3]);
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I parse the integer of the 3rd indexed value after splitting the string. In other words, I take each string "object", split them, then reference the value I want to reference. Then, I just call this class using:

```
    // Import the csv file and assign each row to a list of objects
    List<Object> olReturn = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stats_log.csv"))) {
        olReturn = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    // call to comparator here
        Collections.sort(olReturn, new MyObjectComparator());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this gets me what I need. Thanks for working that out with me!

Answer (score 0):

br.lines() return Stream of String, so underlying object would be String, therefore you just need to do some String indexing to get what you need

```
olReturn = br.lines().sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> Long.valueOf(x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(",") + 1)))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I cannot get this code to work. Perhaps you can fork my version of your code on IdeOne.com, and tweak.  https://ideone.com/JTLhu1

Comment: @Basil in OP's code uses BufferredReader, therefore br.lines() is Stream<String>, so your pseudocode should be something like: https://ideone.com/J1txTV

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid calculating `split` and `Integer.parseInt` in `Comparator` as it is inefficient.

Try this.

```
List<String> list =
    Arrays.asList("Mark,10,0,34", "Wyle,2,0,19", "Tom,2,0,19", "Billy,2,0,7");
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .map(line -> new Object() {
        int sortKey = Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[3]);
        String self = line;
    })
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(object -> object.sortKey))
    .map(object -> object.self)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

output:

```
[Billy,2,0,7, Wyle,2,0,19, Tom,2,0,19, Mark,10,0,34]
```